# Stuck on tensorflow advanced indexing

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given an input tensor of shape (?,5,5) I need to find the max sum for each example by summing elements as specified by an index tensor of shape (120,5,2). The index tensor lists 120 ways to sum an example's 5x5 matrix.
E.g.:

```
Input tensor (?,5,5):
[
  [
    [0,1,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0]
  ],
  [
    ...
  ],
  ...
]

Index tensor(120,5,2):
[
  [
    [0,1], 
    [1,4], 
    [2,2], 
    [3,0], 
    [4,3]  
  ],
  [
    ...
  ],
...
]
```

Here, the result for the *first* summation would be 1+1+0+0+0 = 2.
I need to find the max sum for all 120 ways given by the index array for each example.

In numpy I would use advanced indexing with integer index arrays but unfortunately tf doesn't support this. I found tf.gather_nd but it seems that I this function assumes I know the indices for each example in the batch which I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
The trick is to transpose the axes. That way the unknown dimensions can be pushed to the end and gather_nd can select all slices that come before the unknown dimension.

Here's the full code if anybody cares...

```
def permute(a, l, r):
    if l==r:
        yield list(zip([0,1,2,3,4],a))
    else:
        for i in range(l,r+1):
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
            yield from permute(a, l+1, r)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]

def multi_class_acc_positions(pred, target, input):
    pred_5x5 = tf.reshape(pred, [-1, 5, 5])
    target_5x5 = tf.reshape(target, [-1, 5, 5])
    pred_5x5_T = tf.transpose(pred_5x5, (1,2,0))
    all_perms = tf.constant(list(permute([0,1,2,3,4],0,4)))
    selected_elemens_per_example = tf.gather_nd(pred_5x5_T, all_perms)
    sums_per_example = tf.reduce_sum(selected_elemens_per_example, axis=1)
    best_perm_per_example_index = tf.argmax(sums_per_example, axis=0)
    best_perms = tf.gather_nd(all_perms, best_perm_per_example_index[:,tf.newaxis])[:,:,1]
    pred_5x5_one_hot = tf.reshape(tf.one_hot(best_perms, depth=5), (-1, 5, 5))
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred_5x5_one_hot, axis=2), tf.argmax(target_5x5, axis=2))
    all_correct = tf.reduce_min(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), 1)
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(all_correct)
    return acc
```